# Hibernate can't create a table in MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to save something in database using Hibernate.  Here is how I'm trying do this:

```
    MyEvent event = new MyEvent();
    event.setEventName("Sample event!!!");

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(event);
    session.flush();
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
```

Here is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEvent {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String eventName;

public MyEvent() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEventName() {
    return eventName;
}

public void setEventName(String eventName) {
    this.eventName = eventName;
}
}
```

And here is my config file (hibernate.cfg.xml under the resources directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8877/hibernate_db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hiber</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.smola.MyEvent"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here are dependencies from my pom.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Mysql is running in the Docker container. Here is how the docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hibernate_db
      - MYSQL_USER=hiber
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 8877:3306
```

When I've created the table manually and change the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property to update, it works.

I want to create tables automatically. I can connect to the database, so it isn't the problem with the Docker. What should I change? 
The error communicate looks like this:

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate_db.MyEvent' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Read the sql. It is trying to create the table under the schema hibernate_db in whatever database you are using.

Comment: Also, if you go beyond a POC, you will quickly find that hibernate and ORM layers in general introduce more issues than they resolve. Do a quick internet search on people ripping hibernate out of a project after it was "completed"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What should I use instead of Hibernate or other ORM ?

Comment: I use the spring jdbc extensions, using the rowmapper interface. Spring has a rowmapper that uses jpa annotations, but we had to extend it quite a bit to make it sufficiently useful for a robust system

Comment: @MarcinS  whats the value you are using in hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property now ?

Comment: I've started my project once again following this tutorial: http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/maven/maven_hibernate_example.php and now it works. I think that I missed something in my configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do Here are the differences between hbm2ddl values.

Answer (score 0):

Use spring data to get rid of all thos config isues